# Herbrand Logic-Fitch System

Tags: logic, quantifiers, quantifier-elimination

Given $$\forall x.(p(x) \implies q(x))\quad and \quad p(a)$$ use the Fitch system to prove q(a)

I have started:
$$\\$$

$$1) \forall X.(p(X) \implies q(X)) \qquad (Premise)$$

$$2) p(a) \qquad (Premise)$$

$$3) \exists X.p(X) \qquad (Existential \quad Introduction:2)$$

$$\\$$
but I do not know how to continue. I believe I must prove also $$\forall x.(p(x) \implies q(a))$$ and by existential elimination I will get q(a). Can anyone help?

Comment: Can you explain your choice for step 3?  That is, why did you choose to existential introduction?  Have you considered any alternatives?  What can you do with the first premise?

Comment: I did it in order to prove EX.(pX) and AX.(p(x)=>q(a)) and by existential elimination I would get q(a). With the first premise I can get q(x), using implication elimination

Comment: That's not how those rules work.  Peter Smith's answer is good advice.  At the very least, read about [universal elimination/instantiation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_instantiation).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need, at line 3, to instantiate the universal quantifier with the only available constant ...

The fact that you ask this exceedingly elementary question here suggests that you badly need to do some basic reading to get the hang of deductions in predicate logic: try e.g. Paul Teller's treatment of a Fitch-style system [in his freely available Modern Primer.](http://tellerprimer.ucdavis.edu/) which has lots of worked examples clearly explained.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I will read it! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Its on page 69 of (*), just stop on line 4:

```
1 forall x (p(x) -> q(x)). P
2 p(a)                     P
--------------------------
3 p(a) -> q(a)             1, forall elimination
4 q(a)                     2,3 implication elimination
```

PROLOG can be viewed doing the same inference:

```
?- [user].
q(X) :- p(X).
p(a).

?- q(a).
Yes
```

Bye

(*)
http://tellerprimer.ucdavis.edu/pdf/2ch5.pdf